# Javascript output showing NAN values?

Tags: javascript

Javascript output showing Nan when i enter large values like 6564646464,6516654,555 input values?

```js
$("#calculate").click(function () {


  var need_hotel = $("#hotel_need").val();
  var event_day = $("#event_day").val();
  var result_1 = parseFloat(need_hotel * event_day);
  var result_2 = result_1 * 165;
  var result_3 = result_2 * 0.03;
  $("#ans1").text(result_1.toFixed(2));
  $("#ans2").text(result_2.toFixed(2));
  $("#ans3").text('£' + (result_3).toLocaleString('en'));


  $("#results_container").show();

});
```

Comment: `parseFloat(need_hotel*event_day);` is probably resulting in `NaN`? What is `need_hotel` and `event_day`?

Comment: `parseFloat(need_hotel*event_day)` is an obvious sign for a mistake, as the multiplication operator in javascript always returns a number, therefore it is unnecessary. You did realize however, that you need to convert `string` to `number` at least somewhere, so when it is wrong there, it is missing elsewhere.

Comment: that are input values

Comment: @umair I'm aware that they're input values. What are the values?

Comment: The calculator i have used in the above website and shared its JS code with you.

Comment: When i enter 10,000 and 15,000 and 3 values then it gives NAN output.But it should give value

Comment: @umair please include all relevant information in the question itself? rather than asking us to visit an external website (which may not exist after a while)

Comment: @umair `'10,000' * '15,000'` is `NaN` probably because of the commas in the value. Try converting them to numbers individually first before multiplying?

Comment: How i can get the results with commas?

Comment: _"Try converting them to numbers individually first before multiplying?"_

Comment: Actually i don't know how to do it?Can you help me regarding that?

Comment: But you're using it in the example? `parseFloat` however you will probably need to remove commas (not periods/decimals) first. `'10,000'.replace(',','')`

Comment: In the input values i can use any number.The input values should be in commas because we should have numbers in thousands seperator

Comment: I have used that code to make thousand seperator to input values  onFocus="this.type='number'; this.value=this.lastValue" 
         onBlur="this.type=''; this.lastValue=this.value; this.value=this.value==''?'':(+this.value).toLocaleString()"

Comment: JavaScript numbers do not have a thousands separator which is why it must be removed.

Answer (score -1):

Javascript has iffy support for such large numbers
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER

You might wanna try `BigInt`
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt

Comment: That's a comment/opinion, but not an answer.

Comment: IEEE float64 has around 16-17 decimal digits precision, and when i interpret the question input example(s) as a list (because two commas don't otherwise make sense), the longest has ten digits. However, the question is a bit unclear, so who knows.